# SAS to PySpark conversion using lag function or by other methods equivalent to what to achieve in SAS

Tags: pyspark, sas

I am rewriting legacy SAS codes to PySpark. In one of those blocks, the SAS codes used the lag function. The way I understood the notes, it says an ID is a duplicate if it as two intake dates that are less than 4 days apart.

```
/*Next create flag if the same ID has two intake dates less than 4 days apart*/
/*Data MUST be sorted by ID and DESCENDING IntakeDate!!!*/
data duplicates (drop= lag_ID  lag_IntakeDate);
 set df2;
 by ID;
    lag_ID = lag(ID);
    lag_INtakeDate = lag(IntakeDate);
    if ID = lag_ID then do;
        intake2TIME = intck('day', lag_IntakeDate, IntakeDate);
        end;
    if 0 <= abs(intake2TIME) < 4 then DUPLICATE = 1;
run;
/* If the DUPLICATE > 1, then it is a duplicate and eventually will be dropped.*/
```

I tried meeting the condition as described in the comments: I pulled by sql the ID and intake dates ordered by ID and descending intake date:

```
SELECT ID, intakeDate, col3, col4
from df order by ID, intakeDate DESC
```

I googled the lag equivalent and this is what I found:
https://www.educba.com/pyspark-lag/

However, I have not used window function before, the concept introduced by the site does not somehow make sense to me, though I tried the following to check if my understanding of WHERE EXISTS might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM df
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM df v2 
    WHERE df.ID = v2.ID AND DATEDIFF(df.IntakeDate, v2.IntakeDate) > 4 ) 
/* not sure about the second condition, though*/)
```

Initial df

```
+-----------+------------------+
|         Id|        IntakeDate|
+-----------+------------------+
|        5.0|        2021-04-14|
|        5.0|        2021-05-06|
|        5.0|        2021-05-08|
|       10.0|        2021-04-21|
|       10.0|        2021-05-25|
|       14.0|        2021-03-08|
|       14.0|        2021-03-09|
|       14.0|        2021-09-30|
|       14.0|        2022-04-08|
|       15.0|        2021-04-27|
|       15.0|        2021-05-18|
|       15.0|        2022-01-17|
|       26.0|        2021-08-27|
|       26.0|        2021-09-17|
+-----------+------------------+
```

expected df will have row dropped if the next intakedate is less than 3 days of the prior date

```
+-----------+------------------+
|         Id|        IntakeDate|
+-----------+------------------+
|        5.0|        2021-04-14|
|        5.0|        2021-05-06| row to drop
|        5.0|        2021-05-08|
|       10.0|        2021-04-21|
|       10.0|        2021-05-25|
|       14.0|        2021-03-08| row to drop
|       14.0|        2021-03-09|
|       14.0|        2021-09-30|
|       14.0|        2022-04-08|
|       15.0|        2021-04-27|
|       15.0|        2021-05-18|
|       15.0|        2022-01-17|
|       26.0|        2021-08-27|
|       26.0|        2021-09-17|
+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: If you're only dealing with the 4 days difference issue a self join is easier? However, that step also calculates the intake2Time variable which is not dropped but assuming that's out of the scope of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.window as Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

lead_over_id = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('IntakeDate')

df = (df
    .withColumn('lead_1_date', F.lag('IntakeDate', -1).over(lead_over_id))
    .withColumn('date_diff', F.datediff('IntakeDate', 'lead_1_date'))
    .where((F.col('date_diff') > 4) | F.col('date_diff').isnull())
    .drop('lead_1_date', 'date_diff')
)
```